# Socialite function getId() is working but id is not added in database phpmyadmin

Tags: laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-socialite

I am using Laravel Socialite for google login all the scoialite functions are working fine and data is being added to the database(phpmyadmin) except for the provider_id which function is getId() which is also working fine but data is not inserted in Db.

```
public function handleProviderCallback()
    {

        try{
            $socialUser = Socialite::driver('google')->user();

        }catch(Exception $e){
            redirect('/');

        }
        $socialProvider = SocialProvider::where('provider_id', $socialUser->getId())->first();
        if(!$socialProvider){
            //create new user
            $user = User::firstOrCreate(
                ['email' => $socialUser->getEmail()],
                ['name' => $socialUser->getName()]

            );


            $user->socialProviders()->create(
                ['provider_id' => $socialUser->getId() , 'provider' => 'google']
            );
        }
        else{

            $user = $socialProvider->user;
        }

        auth()->login($user);
         return redirect('/home');
        //return $socialUser->getId();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'provider_id'` must be the `protected $fillable` array on the `SocialProvider` model if you want to pass it in the array to `SocialProvider->create(...)`.